# Python "input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3"

Tags: python, input

I have seen loads of answers that say to use {} or str() + to make the input() only get given 1 argument.

**But what parts of the input need to go with those?** This is my code

```
name.append(input("What is their name"))
score.append(input("What did", name[x], "score"))
```

I'm pretty sure the 3 arguments are the "what did", "name[]x" and "score"
How would I make these one argument while keeping the same order and meaning?

Comment: You can append only 1 argument to a list..

Comment: Am I not only appending one thing to the list? Whatever the user puts?

Comment: Try formatting as @Philipp Ploder answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format the string so that you only pass 1 argument:

```
score.append(input("What did %s score" % name[x]))
```

However if you want to add multiple arguments do this:

```
score.append(input("%s scored %d points!" % (name[x], points)))
```

Comment: Okay! That has fixed the input. However, later on, when I try to print the mean average of the 5 scores, it says "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'" It is clearly something wrong with the type of things getting added together (All the items in the score list) but do I need to change all the items in that list to floats?

Comment: @rosteratbest I adjusted my answer, %s is for strings, %d is for integers and %f is for floating point values

Answer (score 0):

You are adding three arguments in total while the function expects only one so pass one argument only:

```
name.append(input("What is their name"))
score.append(input("What did %s score" % name[x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` syntax is the old syntax.  Try to learn the new syntax as well

```
score.append(input("What did {} score".format(name[x])))
```

This website has some good breakdowns of common usages between the old and the new: https://pyformat.info/