# How to add numbers in input in a Python for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, typeerror, user-input

I'm stuck here:

```py
repeat = int(input("How many : "))
number = 0
nArr = []

for i in range(repeat):
  number += 1
  name = input("Line-",number,": ")
  nArr.append(name)

print(nArr)
```

I'm trying to get output like:

```py
How many : 3
Line-1 : Hello
Line-2 : World
Line-3 : Today
['Hello', 'World', 'Today']
```

However, this program error occurs:

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 3

But I don't know how. Please, can someone advise where?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use format

```
input("Write this number {}: ".format(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a `print()` function to print `"Line-",number,": "`.

Why `name = input("Line-",number,": ")` won't work is because instead of concatenating the strings, Python thinks you're passing 3 arguments to `input()`: `"Line-"`, `number` and `": "`. But as `input()` takes only 1 argument (whatever the user types in, as a string), it throws that error. Looks like you're confused with string concatenation and the arguments passed to `print()`.

**`print()`** takes *any* number of arguments, and displays them in the console altogether, with additional parameters/options for changing how the data should be displayed etc.
See [Python "input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682861/python-input-expected-at-most-1-arguments-got-3).

**Using `print()`**:

```py
show_what_to_enter = print("Line-",number,": ") #just print and tell which line the user has to input
name = input() #wait for and get user input
nArr.append(name)
```

but this has some issues with how the data is being displayed, so the optional parameters `end` and `sep` can be used to get the same output as the one we get using `input()`, by changing `show_what_to_enter` like this:

```py
show_what_to_enter = print("Line-",number,": ", end="", sep="")
```

So, the full code would be:

```py
repeat = int(input("How many : "))
number = 0
nArr = []

for i in range(repeat):
  number += 1
  show_what_to_enter = print("Line-",number,": ", end="", sep="")
  name = input()
  nArr.append(name)

print(nArr)
```

**Using `input()`**:

```py
name = input("Line-" + str(number) + ": ") 
#str(number) because number is an int, and an int and a string cant be concatenated
```

The full code:

```py
repeat = int(input("How many : "))
number = 0
nArr = []

for i in range(repeat):
  number += 1
  name = input("Line-" + str(number) + ": ")
  nArr.append(name)

print(nArr)
```